# Overriding template logic in TowerJS Views

Tags: towerjs, coffeekup

How do I override how templates are rendered in TowerJS? I know I can use Jade, but if I stuck with CoffeeKup, how could I, for instance have this code:

```
formFor @user, (form) ->
  form.fieldset "Profile", (fields) ->
    fields.field "firstName"
    fields.field "lastName"
    fields.field "email"
  form.fieldset "Address", (fields) ->
    fields.field "lat", as: hidden
    fields.field "lng", as: hidden
    fields.field "street"
    fields.field "city", as: "select", collection: ["CA"]
```

... generate this:

```
<form class='form' data-method='post' method='post' novalidate='true' role='form'>
  <fieldset class='fieldset' id='profile'>
    <legend class='legend'>
      <span>Profile</span>
    </legend>
    <li class='field-list'>
      <li class='field string optional validate'>
        <label class='label' for='active-record-user-first-name-input'>
          <span>First Name</span>
```

...instead of this:

```
<form class='form' data-method='post' method='post' novalidate='true' role='form'>
  <fieldset class='fieldset' id='profile'>
    <legend class='legend'>
      <span>Profile</span>
    </legend>
    <ol class='field-list'>
      <li class='field string optional validate'>
        <label class='label' for='active-record-user-first-name-input'>
          <span>First Name</span>
```

I guess I'm nitpicking over the `<ol>` versus `<ul>`, but I am just starting use Tower in evaluation to Railway and Derby. Is this a CoffeKup question or Mint question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize that tag by setting:

```
Tower.View.fieldListTag = 'ul' # or whatever
```

The configuration variables are here:

- [https://github.com/viatropos/tower/tree/master/packages/tower-view/shared/view.coffee#L16-92](https://github.com/viatropos/tower/blob/399fff92ed6477c123fa11bfb5b07405436a87d7/packages/tower-view/shared/view.coffee#L16-92)

Comment: Thanks! I see now that I can change that and other settings in `config/application`.